# Weird bash results using cut

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cut

I am trying to run this command:

```
./smstocurl SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896
```

`smstocurl` script:

```
#SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896
model=$(echo \&model=$1 | cut -d'.' -f 1)
echo $model
imea1=$(echo \&simImea1=$1 | cut -d'.' -f 2)
echo $imea1
imea2=$(echo \&simImea2=$1 | cut -d'.' -f 3)
echo $imea2
echo $model$imea1$imea2
```

Result Received

```
&model=SLASH2911325850268888911325850268896
```

Result Expected

```
&model=SLASH2&simImea1=911325850268888&simImea2=911325850268896
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: So did our answers solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, give me some time to accept one, based on which I choose.

Comment: Oook indeed! No problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are `cut`ting based on the dot `.`. In the first case your desired string contains the first string, the one containing `&model`, so then it is printed.

However, in the other cases you get the 2nd and 3rd blocks (`-f2`, `-f3`), so that the `imea` text gets cutted off.

Instead, I would use something like this:

```
while IFS="." read -r model imea1 imea2
do
    printf "&model=%s&simImea1=%s&simImea2=%s\n" $model $imea1 $imea2
done <<< "$1"
```

Note the usage of `printf` and variables to have more control about what we are writing. Using a lot of escapes like in your `echo`s can be risky.

#### Test

```
while IFS="." read -r model imea1 imea2; do printf "&model=%s&simImea1=%s&simImea2=%s\n" $model $imea1 $imea2
done <<< "SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896"
```

Returns:

```
&model=SLASH2&simImea1=911325850268888&simImea2=911325850268896
```

---

Alternatively, this `sed` makes it:

```
sed -r 's/^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$/\&model=\1\&simImea1=\2\&simImea2=\3/' <<< "$1"
```

by catching each block of words separated by dots and printing back.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this way

**Run:**

```
./program SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
String=`echo $1 | sed "s/\./\&simImea1=/"`
String=`echo $String | sed "s/\./\&simImea2=/"`
echo "&model=$String
```

**Output:**

```
&model=SLASH2&simImea1=911325850268888&simImea2=911325850268896
```

Comment: This is a bit overkilling. Too much `echo` and `sed` for something that can be handled perfectly with bash builtins. Also, it is good practice to quote when `echo`ing.

Comment: Also, `$()` is preferred over the use of backticks. And `cmd <<< word` is better than `echo word | cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

awk way

```
awk -F. '{print "&model="$1"&simImea1="$2"&simImea2="$3}' <<< "SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896"
```

or

```
awk -F. '$0="&model="$1"&simImea1="$2"&simImea2="$3' <<< "SLASH2.911325850268888.911325850268896"
```

#### output

```
&model=SLASH2&simImea1=911325850268888&simImea2=911325850268896
```